# MySQL triggers integer variable

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to do something like this:

```
DECLARE VAR_NAME INT DEFAULT 0;

IF NEW.field_name != NULL THEN
  SET VAR_NAME := 8;
END IF;

IF NEW.field_name = NULL THEN
  SET VAR_NAME := 1;
END IF;

UPDATE table_name SET column_name = column_name + VAR_NAME WHERE table_id = NEW.given_id;
```

I have a trigger for when inserting a new value:

I declare a variable, I change its value based on some conditions and then I update a table by adding this value to the current value of a specific column where the condition is met 'table_id = NEW.given_id'

Even I don't get errors the desired result is not happening.

Comment: Use `NEW.field_name IS NOT NULL` instead of `NEW.field_name != NULL` and `NEW.field_name IS NULL` instead of `NEW.field_name = NULL`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yeap that did the trick. Ευχαριστώ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, as the comments indicate, you can't check for NULL with normal equality operators. The way that I understand this is that nothing is equal to, less than, or greater than, etc, NULL, as NULL is literally 'no value'.

You must instead use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` to check for NULL.

This link goes into further detail:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the link as well.